# I can't pass a parameter to a function the variable goes undefined, Angular 11

Tags: angular

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.user = localStorage.getItem('user');

     //If I console log this.user I get a json but this.user.uid gets undefined

    this.accounts.getAccountData(this.user.uid,(res) => {
    this.playerData = res;
    });

}
```

The variable this.user.uid when I do a console.log it appears undefined every time.

the json

```json
"uid":"fEPuVlR6pMQni8S1X8kJWCKCyhp1","displayName":"Robert Borya","photoURL":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-70SBoFxWIe4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn-2bnWj4XbYczROASdVrQcPBPhLA/s96-c/photo.jpg","email":"robertborya@gmail.com","emailVerified":true,"phoneNumber":null,"isAnonymous":false,"tenantId":null,"providerData":[{"uid":"106899152313188439706","displayName":"Robert Borya","photoURL":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-70SBoFxWIe4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn-2bnWj4XbYczROASdVrQcPBPhLA/s96-c/photo.jpg","email":"robertborya@gmail.com","phoneNumber":null,"providerId":"google.com"}],"apiKey":"AIzaSyAzZVVjLoHeTBkAaU3QxWvPyHTPHFaQyBU","appName":"[DEFAULT]","authDomain":"angularstrat.firebaseapp.com","stsTokenManager":{"apiKey":"AIzaSyAzZVVjLoHeTBkAaU3QxWvPyHTPHFaQyBU","refreshToken":"AOvuKvRa5eU4FIUO5bX1xn5T6nIp6s6VK4zkI6CKjdDPJXHET4Q66oPsCVVLngSST6I7HPbJESyHykk4siq8pgaSlukJZMNwruv2oa0aABgvZjVAJaa0ribSfoDaHhLFzWHspMOeAYZEwqgVvEw23B5crVck_yYLkuoJbPpqWxnfDB9_zoD5Rqaog5HrnXe_WCjf3d5ynXZMEVrOhfOCYloRBNUBRSHeobgvv6cQeiTROl13zYWbbl7V_ce2Skenf5m0Uh9uDwcTJ9Ip4FGkpV-HyR3iGFWpyGerM2IanPGwJ6zqIoV-o44F8aO8nHm0rl0Dw3XH-VcbG4ra5UrN0mU8kjbZMXMJZaKxb6dgH8EXpHMJXEMLR23DL97SE_e094SyLoyeH4ZacOLmLaOSxC-Uut_WIs6R1exf7deAMaaqesIhVOhFOehflV4G9B-yN2TQdxnGFC_M-2TSKO88fEYLDRaBkmfUhQ","accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjYxMDgzMDRiYWRmNDc1MWIyMWUwNDQwNTQyMDZhNDFkOGZmMWNiYTgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.I6qOCplqdNRGGCmbIok51Namn_qWwGMcarrzNnMIGSjDSbuGeKXZOtpPr_IHF0PjcjB4v8nRP6ELz3Y2lY8453LUpNY_kduP-5jNZwUiJAQQdd_S5r4iIEfIbdDIlHEC9NgYBL9J__C15hQU1tbpq5sgeMoeek4U3ZoshQK71lJ0GedyLqLxXVp7Q_zxWn5_38AEGfRVBiGYkoUEtV8llWf72sSqnV_OPPCCbLXsMf7K7zWwjg14ngHKU57aqJ1l_PyrrhL7E9oZ9X2PEvwq43IxhWYeFsJMm8L166l3Yu3ZoUOx185lndVrBhrGoAijXdmtPwcjXgh0SC3xQtmQEA","expirationTime":1613213579000},"redirectEventId":null,"lastLoginAt":"1613209979068","createdAt":"1613032968164","multiFactor":{"enrolledFactors":[]}}
```

Should I make the function return?

Comment: Please, give us a [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If the variable appear `undefined`, then the variable must be `undefined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183975/update-data-to-api-based-on-dropdown      please  help me in angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176860/issue-while-binding-data-to-form-array-textboxes-in-angular       please help me in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the value:

```
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Comment: Yeah that was it!!! why is this necessary?

Comment: Everything in localStorage is just a string..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183975/update-data-to-api-based-on-dropdown      please help me in angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176860/issue-while-binding-data-to-form-array-textboxes-in-angular      please help me in angular